# Script to restore db and close connections?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Im looking for a scrip that I can just point at a .bak file and it will delete the current db and then restore the .bak file in its place. And will close all connections. Does anybody know of a script that will do this?

I want to do it in c#.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466651/how-to-restore-a-database-from-c-sharp it's asked before!

Comment: I dont know where I can get the dlls from?

Answer (score 0):

You should start by looking at SQL Server Management Object, in particular [the Restore class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.aspx).