# Restore failed for Server '\\.\pipe\81DAC374-2583-49\tsql\query'

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, smo

Error : ****"Restore failed for Server '\.\pipe\81DAC374-2583-49\tsql\query'."****

i get the error here `resDB.SqlRestore(sv)`
My backup works fine but restore fails.i am trying to get it working from the past two days and no luck yet.

```
   Public Shared Sub RestoreBackup()
        Dim sConnect As String = My.Settings.LICConnectionString
        Dim dbName As String

        Using cnn As New SqlConnection(sConnect)
            cnn.Open()
            dbName = cnn.Database.ToString()
            cnn.ChangeDatabase("master")

            Dim sc As New ServerConnection(cnn)
            Dim sv As New Server(sc)

            ' Check that I'm connected to the user instance
            MsgBox(sv.InstanceName.ToString())

            ' Create backup device item for the backup
            Dim bdi As New BackupDeviceItem("C:\Backup\LIC.bak", DeviceType.File)

            ' Create the restore object
            Dim resDB As New Restore()
            resDB.Devices.Add(bdi)
            resDB.NoRecovery = False
            resDB.ReplaceDatabase = True
            resDB.Database = dbName

            ' Restore the database
            resDB.SqlRestore(sv)
            MsgBox("Your database has been restored.")
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Why does it fail??Any Help Appreciated.

Comment: You should be very, very thankful the code failed.

Comment: @AndrewBarber [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2007/03/20/backup-and-restore-with-user-instances.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2007/03/20/backup-and-restore-with-user-instances.aspx)

Comment: I have no clue why you put my name on that link.

Comment: @AndrewBarber   I am sorry..i just wanted to show you that i am using this code snippet...kindly help me fix the error...and why should i be thankful the code failed??please explain.

Comment: Explain with words, not links with *no* explanation at all.

Comment: my backup works fine but restore fails with the given error...can you please tell me what am i doing wrong??

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to restore over the master database.  You will need to change `cnn.ChangeDatabase("master")` to `cnn.ChangeDatabase("LIC").`

**EDIT:**

Alternatively, remove the line `cnn.ChangeDatabase("master")` altogether and add the following line after instantiating the Restore class:

```
resDB.Action = RestoreActionType.Database
```

Also, if the backup is from another server you may want to look at using `RelocateFile` - [How to restore a database from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466651/how-to-restore-a-database-from-c-sharp)

Comment: [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2007/03/20/backup-and-restore-with-user-instances.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2007/03/20/backup-and-restore-with-user-instances.aspx)

Comment: @SunnyBhattacharjee I have updated the answer re. the link you have posted.